# Cookie control access to a express directory

Tags: node.js, express

I have two directories

```
app.use('/public',  express.static(__dirname + '/' + env + '/src/app/public'));
app.use('/private', express.static(__dirname + '/' + env + '/src/app/private'));
```

I just want to control access to /private by some header params, I tried:

```
app.all("/private", requireLogin, function(req, res, next) {
  next(); 
});
```

But the requireLogin function is never called. Maybe there is another solution outside.... thanks!

Comment: have you tried with wildcard?  app.all('/private/*', requireLogin, etc)?

Comment: Thanks but it does not work!
I am using the next function, to check every request to NodeJS

    app.use(function (req, res, next){
       ...
    }
    app.use('/private', express.static(__dirname + '/' + env + '/src/app/private'));

I can control when someone is accessing to /private, but I have ahother call for a proxy simulation and NodeJS stop serving then.

    app.get('/api', function (req, res, next) {
        ....
    });)